# Show hide a div with a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In the example below, I'm trying to show a `div` when a user clicks a link and also close the same `div` when the link is clicked.

The problem is with the code in-between, that checks if a `div` is visible at the time the link is clicked. Now, clicking the same link does not hide the `div`, which Is what I hoped for.

I'm kinda stuck on this. It's simple, but I just cannot figure how to get it right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Generated by Edit Plus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/site/css/bootstrap.css" 
      media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addUser").click(function(){
        if($('.demoForm').is(':visible')){
            $('.demoForm').hide();
        }
            $(this).parent().find(".demoForm").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.toolOptions{
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

        <div>
        <div class="addUser">Add a new user
          <span class="demoForm" style="display:none;">I'm the form div.</span>
        </div> 
        </div> 

        <div>
        <div class="addUser">Add a new user
          <span class="demoForm" style="display:none;">I'm the form div.</span>
        </div> 
        </div> 

        <div>
        <div class="addUser">Add a new user
          <span class="demoForm" style="display:none;">I'm the form div.</span>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To all who replied, the `if` is there to remove any existing div that is visible. I first look for any existing visible div, then close that, then open a new one near it's parent. That's the way it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to previous answers, you can still use your logics, just ignore current item.
Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDNJ6/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".addUser").click(function(){
         var form = $(this).find(".demoForm");
         $('.demoForm').not(form).hide();        
         form.toggle();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Yw, plenty of answers while I was creating jsfiddle sample. Don't forget to choose one as answer.

Comment: In your code, how can I pick out only forms that are visible? There might be a lot for forms on the page and acting on each of them make take time (like your code does). So form = .demoForm that is visible only. Is that possible?

Comment: You can add pseudo selector `:visible`, e.g. `$('.demoForm:visible').not(form).hide();`. Though this depends on how many elements do you have? Untill you have a couple of thousands you won't feel any difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addUser").click(function(){    
      var current=$(this).parent().find(".demoForm");// current element
            $('.demoForm').not(current).hide();    //hide the rest
            $(this).parent().find(".demoForm").toggle();//toggle the current
    });
});
</script>
```

This much is sufficient in js code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
    var $demoForm = $(this).find('.demoForm');
    $demoForm.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".addUser").click(function(){
        if($('.demoForm').is(':visible')){
            $('.demoForm').hide();
        }
            $(this).find(".demoForm").toggle();
    });
```

or better

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
            $(this).find(".demoForm").toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `toggleClass` for this see http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

use a class like this

```
.display
{
display:none;
}
```

toggle this class on the click of link

```
$("#link").click(function(){
$("#test").toggleClass("display");
})
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8Xpwx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit some lines.

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".demoForm").toggle();
});
```